# Setting plainchant in musixtex

Tags: musixtex

I want to add an extraxt from a plainchant piece to an article. This is what I wrote, in as musixdoc.pdf suggestet:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\title{\LARGE title}
\input musixtex
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\tableofcontent
\instrumentnumber1
\setstaffs1{1}
\setlines1{4}
\setclef1{4000}
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\generalmeter{\empty}
\smallmusicsize
\startextract
\NOtes\squ{M}\enotes
\endextract
\end{document}
```

And this is the error that occurs:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\altoc@si ->\gregorianCclef
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Gregorian-chant notation in `musixtex` you must `\input musixgre`. This is not very clearly explained in the manual on p. 87.

```
\documentclass[13pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{musixtex} % Do \usepackage for LaTeX instead of Plain-style `\input`
\input musixgre % ADD THIS
\title{\LARGE title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
\begin{music} % better to wrap it in music environment, I think
\instrumentnumber1
\setstaffs1{1}
\setlines1{4}
\setclef1{4000}
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\generalmeter{\empty}
\smallmusicsize
\startextract
\NOtes\squ{M}\enotes
\zendextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]